# How to format HTML code in VScode ?

Tags: html, formatting, visual-studio-code

I would like to find a way to format HTML in VScode, such as fro example, if I have a long div like this one:

```
<div class="signal-item-icon checkbox-signal signal-icon" [class.selected]="signal.isSelectedCheckSign" (click)="$event.stopPropagation(); onSelectOneShadowSignal(signal);">
```

I want it to be displayed like this when I do ctrl+shift+i:

```
<div class="signal-item-icon checkbox-signal signal-icon" 
     [class.selected]="signal.isSelectedCheckSign" 
     (click)="$event.stopPropagation(); 
     onSelectOneShadowSignal(signal);">
```

Do you if it is possible? Is there an extension VScode that exists for this kind of implementation?

Thank you !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Setting the VSCode preference `html.format.wrapAttributes` to `force` will accomplish the formatting from your example.

Answer (score 5):

You can also use it with combination of `html.format.wrapLineLength`.

```json
"html.format.wrapLineLength": 80,
"html.format.wrapAttributes": "auto",
```

In this case, attributes starts wrapping when line length exceeds `80`. It's useful when you have many attributes and it will fill the empty spaces on the right.

Answer (score 1):

I think a better solution would be to use the VSCode `html.format.wrapAttributes` option of `force-aligned`. This doesn't blur the line between the next nested object and your attributes of your parent. (In most cases).

force

```
<form attribute1="value" 
  attribute2="othervalue">
  <div></div>
</form>
```

force-aligned

```
<form attribute1="value" 
      attribute2="othervalue">
  <div></div>
</form>
```

In my opinion, the first option makes it harder to find the div inside the form. And I've seen it cause many developers headaches when this happens.

```
<form attribute1="value">
  attribute2="othervalue"
  <div></div>
</form>
```